# Some basic questions about creating a webform handler from the module webform_example_handler

Tags: 8, webforms

I'm "cutting my teeth" in Drupal 8 on the Webform module so these are going to be rather naive questions.

I need to programmatically fill a URL field in the form with an XML file that
I generate from the other data in the form and do it just before the submit
so that the form is complete. To do so I figured using a webform handler is
the way to go and I have been using `webform_example_handler` as my
template.

Now for my ridiculous naivety, just a few basic questions:

In `webform_example_handler.schema.yml` the first line is:
`"webform.handler.example"`. Is this a standard Drupal construct of `<webform>.<handler>.<my_module>`, or
something specific that must be followed set by the webform module
or am I completely off base on how this is derived?

I would guess that for my
module the line would be: `webform.handler.dis_doc_gen`?

The `"webform.webform.webform_example_handler.yml"` file: could someone explain the parts? In my module would it be: `webform.webform.dis_doc_gen.yml` ?

Last: I have built my webform through the interface so I assume that I don't
need the file `"webform.webform.webform_example_handler.yml"` as that would
only be for creating a webform from a yml file upon installing the module as
far as I can tell. However, is there something in my webform that I need to
set so that it knows about my
`".../dis_doc_gen/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/DISDocGenWebformHandler.php"`
handler?

Could someone please tell me what key thing(s) I need to do to make that connection or is that all automatic as long as you clear the Plugin cache? (I just discovered that cache through the "Admin Toolbar" module).

I realize this could be done through one of the webform hooks but I would rather use a handler as part of getting familiar with Drupal 8 in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could someone please tell me what key thing(s) I need to do to make
>   that connection

There are 4 ways that you can tell Drupal that your plugin exists.

You can read about the other 3 at [D8 Plugin discovery](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/plugin-api/d8-plugin-discovery)

In this case [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) uses:

> **AnnotatedClassDiscovery**
>
> The AnnotatedClassDiscovery class uses name of the [annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) that
>   contains the plugin definition, e.g., `@Plugin`, `@EntityType`, in plugin
>   docblocks to discover plugins, minimizing memory usage during the
>   discovery phase. The AnnotatedClassDiscovery class takes an argument
>   in its constructor, `$subdir`, which specifies the
>   sub-directory/sub-namespace for this plugin type. The
>   AnnotatedClassDiscovery class scans PSR-4 classes inside those
>   sub-directories of Plugin folders to find plugins (see a
>   "[Annotations-based plugins](https://www.drupal.org/node/1882526)").

Side Note: Entities and blocks also use this "annotation" method.

This "annotation" is seen in [webform_example_handler/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/ExampleWebformHandler.php](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_handler/src/Plugin/WebformHandler/ExampleWebformHandler.php#L21)

[image]

Yes, this info is inside a comment block, weird, but that's just how it works.

---

> In [webform_example_handler.schema.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_handler/config/schema/webform_example_handler.schema.yml) the first line is:
>   `webform.handler.example`. Is this a standard Drupal construct of
>   `<webform>.<handler>.<my_module>`, or something specific that must be
>   followed set by the webform module or am I completely off base on how
>   this is derived?

Wrong, otherwise it would've been named webform.handler.webform_example_handler.

It's actually `webform.handler.<WebformHandler_id>` (The ID you use in the annotation).

This is because your module can have multiple plugins, so it makes no sense to use the module's name here.

---

The [webform.webform.webform_example_handler.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_handler/config/install/webform.webform.webform_example_handler.yml) file: could someone explain the parts? In my module would it be: *webform.webform.dis_doc_gen.yml* ?

Assuming your module is named `dis_doc_gen`, correct.

---

> Last: I have built my webform through the interface so I assume that I
>   don't need the file [webform.webform.webform_example_handler.yml](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/blob/8.x-5.x/modules/webform_example_handler/config/install/webform.webform.webform_example_handler.yml) as
>   that would only be for creating a webform from a yml file upon
>   installing the module as far as I can tell

Correct, anything inside the `/install` folder, runs on install and that file is creating a form. Since you created one via the UI, you don't need this in your use case.

Comment: I've created the class `DisDocGenWebformHandler` but since it's already under the namespace `Drupal\dis_doc_gen\Plugin\WebformHandler` probably `DisDocGen` or `DisDocumentGenerator` would be clearer and avoid redundancy. Is there a convention for this or is this a matter of preference?

Comment: @user5429087 yes there is a convention. `10. Classes and interfaces should have names that stand alone to tell what they do without having to refer to the namespace, read well, and are as short as possible without losing functionality information or leading to ambiguity.` For more info read [Declaring Classes: Naming Conventions](https://www.drupal.org/node/608152#naming)

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else who sees this there is one more step to make it all work, although if you are familiar with D8 you will probably already know this, which is, once you set all this up you must also connect your handler to your form and you do so (in my case since I created the form through the UI) by using  `Webforms:Email/Handlers:Add Handler` where your newly created handler should now show up. You may need to clear the Plugin cache as well.